# ref is possibly null inside forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My App.tsx looks like this

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import InputField from "./InputField";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
 
  const checkInRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  return (
      <InputField        
        ref={checkInRef}
      />
  );
}
```

and InputField.tsx looks like this

```
import {
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  forwardRef,
} from "react";


const InputField = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement>(function (props, ref) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={ref} />
      <button onClick={() => ref.current.focus()}>focus</button>
    </div>
  );
});
export default InputField;
```

The above code works as expected and clicking the button focuses the input field. But i am getting 2 typescript errors

"'ref' is possibly 'null'."

Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>'.
Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void'.

I know that i can pass the ref to a Fc with props as RefObject without using forwardRef. but i want to do this with forwardRef

Answer (score 0):

define `ref` type like this

```
 import React, { RefObject } from "react";

 type OrNull<T> = T | null;


 ref: | RefObject<HTMLInputElement>
      | ((instance: OrNull<HTMLInputElement>) => void)
      | null
      | undefined
  )
```